# How did the Hashirama and Madara statues at the Valley of the End come to be?

Tags: naruto

Were they built by traditional means (as they would've been in our world)? Were they created via some sort of ninjutsu that shaped the rocks that were there? Or was it erected by some sort of Doton jutsu (like some Doryuu Heki)?

I am not sure if there is some canonical answer to this, but I'd like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Whomever maintains the Madara statue's spiky hair is doing one heck of a job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, these statues are not protected or enchanted. After the Naruto vs. Sasuke battle at the Valley of the End, the status were damaged, and later repaired. I believe it was a reconstruction job, much like Leaf's faces on the mountain, or the Kage statues at the Sand.

> #### Words of Madara
>
> I honestly don't think Hashirama would give a damn enough to make statues, let alone self-repairing statues. He wasn't the sentimental type.

Answer (score 1):

It's nowhere stated, where the statues come from. However, after Naruto and Sasuke destroy some parts of the statues, they are restored, later. (Compare chapter 370) That could mean, that they are some special statues, formed or protected by a jutsu.

Maybe, after the battle between Madara and Hashirama (where the valley was formed), Hashirama decided to create these statues to be a sign.

Comment: You think Hashirama could've created them? Did he master Doton? Or do you think he could've done it using some other kind of ninjutsu?

Comment: I really don't know. Maybe he used a special ninjutsu, maybe mokuton (k, I don't know *how* he would use it to make these figures)...

Answer (score 1):

Much like Madara already said, it's not mentioned anywhere that someone had built them.
However, I (Hashirama) *did* know to use Doton, and probably someone created them to make a statement of peace.
As for the repair. It's easy enough for a future Doton user to fix it, I don't think it's self-repairing.

Comment: So your guess is that they were erected with ninjutsu? Because the faces carved in the mountain at Konoha are hand-carved...

Comment: Seeing as how Yamato could make a mokuton ryokan just by having your cells, I suppose making a statue wouldn't be hard for a skilled doton user.

Comment: Not only that, anyone who knows how to use Doton can create Natural raw stone(where is need to be fill). And after that hand-carved them.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju: Ah! That's more likely!